# git error - connection closed by host port 22

Tags: git, ssh, repository, bitbucket, git-clone

I have already generated SSH key and also added that key to bitbucket. I am trying to clone repository from bitbucket. But when I try to clone (SSH url) into my ubuntu system, for 20-25 mins nothing happens, and then after getting an error like

> Connection closed by xx.xx.xx.xx port 22 fatal: Could not read from
> remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Here I am attaching a screenshot of my error.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried https clone?

Comment: Can you run `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` and confirm that your network is permitting that traffic? What about `ssh -Tvp443 git@altssh.bitbucket.org` (which uses a nonstandard port)?